# Как добавить контент во все id элементы?

Tags: javascript

Пишу таймер для товаров, время начало отсчитываться только на одном элементе из пяти

```js
const days = document.getElementById("days");
const hours = document.getElementById("hours");
const mins = document.getElementById("mins");
const sec = document.getElementById("sec");

const currectYear = new Date().getFullYear();
const newYear = new Date(`20 Feb${currectYear} 00:00:00`);


function countDownTimer(){
    const todayDate = Date.now();
    const gap = newYear - todayDate;

    const d = Math.floor(gap / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24); 
    const h = Math.floor((gap / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) % 24);
    const m = Math.floor((gap / 1000 / 60) % 60 );
    const s = Math.floor((gap / 1000) % 60 );

    days.innerHTML =  d < 10 ? "0" + d : d;
    hours.innerHTML = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h; 
    mins.innerHTML =  m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
    sec.innerHTML =  s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;
} setInterval(countDownTimer, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time">
                  <ul class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time__ul">
                    
                      <li class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time__ul_li">
                        <p id="days">00</p>
                        <p>Days</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time__ul_li">
                        <p id="hours">00</p>
                        <p>Hours</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time__ul_li">
                        <p id="mins">00</p>
                        <p>Mins</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time__ul_li">
                        <p id="sec">00</p>
                        <p>Sec</p>
                      </li>
                    
                  </ul>
                </div> 
                
                <div class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time">
                  <ul class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time__ul">
                    
                      <li class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time__ul_li">
                        <p id="days">00</p>
                        <p>Days</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time__ul_li">
                        <p id="hours">00</p>
                        <p>Hours</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time__ul_li">
                        <p id="mins">00</p>
                        <p>Mins</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="new-arrives__product__first__figure__time__ul_li">
                        <p id="sec">00</p>
                        <p>Sec</p>
                      </li>
                    
                  </ul>
                </div>(таких 5 элементов)
```

Comment: ID уникален для каждого элемента. Используйте классы

Comment: а можно как-то одним id это всё сделать или к каждому элементу нужно уникальный id придумать?

Comment: id должен быть уникальным на странице

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `.querySelectorAll()` или `.getElementsByClassName()`. Обратите внимание, что то и  то возвращает коллекцию элементов